# How to concate all array value in array of object in mongoDB?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, object, mongoose

There is a collection named ***group*** in my mongoDb database that contains 2 or more objects. In every objects, there is an array named **members** that includes id of members. If i want to concate all the members id of that array of objects, how would i write mongoose query in Javascript ?

From an **stackoverflow** solution, i tried with this api

```js
//Get All Group Members
postRouter.get(
  "/getMembers",
  expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const members = await Group.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind: "$members", // flatten the "images" array into separate documents
      },
      {
        $group: {
          // group all documents
          _id: null, // into the same bucket
          members: { $push: "$members" }, // and push every image entry into an array called "images"
        },
      },
      {
        $project: {
          _id: 0,
        },
      },
    ]);
    console.log(members);

    res.send(members);
  })
);
```

and I have got this data

```
[
    {
        "members": [
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d51",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d58",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d56",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d51",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d58",
            "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d56"
        ]
    }
]
```

Though it return the exact result, but I dont want the unwanted array and object on top of array, i just need just exact array like this

```
 "members": [
        "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d51",
        "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d58",
        "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d56",
        "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d51",
        "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d58",
        "609bed37f7b8067ea24d1d56"
    ]
```

[image: this is the picture of my database collection]

Comment: you mean `$concatArrays`?

Comment: yah i mean $concateArray from all of the object